# Monitor errors from log

Tags: powershell

I have a process `& some action`
I want to monitor the run log and "capture" the error messages.
I tried to define a variable that "catches" the log `$var=& some action` the problem is that it stores all the log without the errors (the red lines). Using Start-Process is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

A while ago, I created a [`Log-Entry` framework](https://github.com/iRon7/Log-Entry) described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41861276/1701026.
In here I deal with this issue by checking the `Error` object for new errors (described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44441600/1701026) each time a new entry is logged.