# Powershell script to store errors to $Error[0] but it doesn't release it

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv, skype-for-business

I create a script to do 2 jobs:

1. Import CSV file with users email list then assign it to `$emails`
2. Connect to Skype for business online using `-UseOAuth` command within the command `Move-CsUser` with Try and catch switch so if any user didn't move it will save the error to

   ```
   Error: $($Error[0])" |  Out-File c:\temp\CantFind.txt -Append
   ```

   and once the script is done I use `notepad.exe c:\temp\CantFind.txt` to open the text file with a list of the users that error out and the reason why they error out.

The script works perfectly the first time I run it. it shows the list of the users in text file call `cantfind.txt`. Once I import a new user email list and rerun the script still works perfectly but the text file `cantfind.txt` doesn't get updated with the new errors related to the new set of users but it keeps showing the first errors from the first user emails list.

I did try to clear and remove variable commands and I even included a function I founded here on the forums but nothing works `cantfind.txt` doesn't store the new errors anymore and even if I deleted the file it will generate a new file with the same errors I got from the first set of users that I run the first time. any suggestions would be welcome.

```
$emails =  Import-Csv  -path C:\temp\Userlist1.csv -Header Identity
 
foreach ($email in $emails) 
{
     try {
        Move-CsUser -Identity $email.Identity -Target sipfed.online.lync.com -Confirm:$false  -MoveToTeams -Force -UseOAuth
         -BypassAudioConferencingCheck -BypassEnterpriseVoiceCheck -HostedMigrationOverrideUrl 
             https://adminxx.online.lync.com/HostedMigration/hostedmigrationService.svc
     } 
     catch  
     {
         "Error: $($Error[0])" |  Out-File  c:\temp\CantFind.txt -Append
     }  
}  
notepad.exe c:\temp\CantFind.txt
```

Comment: If you are already using `try-catch`, then `$_` in your catch block contains your caught exception.

Comment: What are you talking about?? what exception

Comment: When you are in a catch block, you can call an 'error' also an exception.

Comment: Thus: `"Error: $_" |  Out-File  c:\temp\CantFind.txt -Append`. Also: with version of PowerShell do you use? (Note that PowerShell 5.1 has a `$MaximumErrorCount` preference variable set to: `256`)

Comment: Thanks, @iRon you are the man!! I did update my code to add 'MaximumErrorCount =  512' and my release the value for error form error '"Error: $($Error)" |  Out-File  c:\temp\CantFind.txt' and now works as expected. thanks again. this is the final version **foreach ($email in $emails) {
    try {Move-CsUser -Identity $email.Identity -Target sipfed.online.lync.com -Confirm:$false -UseOAuth -MoveToTeams -Force -BypassAudioConferencingCheck -BypassEnterpriseVoiceCheck -HostedMigrationOverrideUrl https:xsvc 
 } catch {"Error: $($Error)" |  Out-File  c:\temp\CantFind.txt }}c:\temp\CantFind.txt
**

Answer (score 0):

As per comment from @AdminOfThings, you better use the current item (`$PSItem` or just `$_`) which holds the exception raised in the `try` section:

```
try {
    $a = 1/0
}
catch {
    "$_"
}
```

Which returns:

> `Attempted to divide by zero.`

Besides, it is good to know that the `$Error` object holds a limited amount of errors (by default 256). The latest error will be added to the top of the list (`$Error[0]`) and the rest of the error will shift down until the limit is reached and then they will simply drop of.

In **Windows PowerShell** (up and till version 5), you can set the size of the error list with the `$MaximumErrorCount` preference variable. In **PowerShell core** there is an issue, see: [Remove most Maximum* capacity variables](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/2363)

To capture all errors not yet captured, see: [Catching Cascading Errors in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44441600/1701026)